# Deeper server block request

Tags: request, deezer

Today I had a problem searching songs on Deezer API. The server was blocking my requests.

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond 195.244.30.137:80

What do I need to do so that it wouldn't happen again?

Comment: They had some troubles on some of they servers for less than one hour, it should be fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.
There was a internet problem in my side.
Sorry